# including a form element in a .tpl file

Tags: php, smarty

I am using a custom php frame work . i use smarty template engine . i start create a form within the controller file and i introduce a form element in .tpl file using html_checkbox . But this element cannot be found when i submit the form . how do i make  the .tpl content part of the form .

Comment: How does the generated HTML code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create checkboxes using smarty's `{html_checkboxes}`, the name attribute in the smarty function will be used to as the name for the checkboxes.

For example, if your smarty call is:

```
{html_checkboxes name='states' options=$states}
```

The resulting checkboxes will have the name `states[]` which, when submitted, will be placed into a single PHP **array** which can be looped over to determine which states were selected:

```
foreach ($_POST['states'] as $state) {

}
```

Two things to keep in mind: it is up to you to wrap the checkboxes in form tags. Also **if no boxes are checked, they will not be submitted in the form post data**. This is a quirk of HTML and has nothing to do with smarty.